# How do I set up my topsites page on safari.

Tags: imac

My topsites page got wiped out by another site trying to get into my computer.  When I open Safari now all I get is "favorites" - I want "Topsites".  What do I have to do to reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple KB - [View your Top Sites](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/view-your-top-sites-ibrw53c401e7/mac)

> - View the Top Sites page: Choose Bookmarks > Show Top Sites. If you don’t see Show Top Sites, choose Safari > Preferences, click General,
>     then click the “New windows open with” pop-up menu and choose Top
>     Sites.
> - You can also see the Top Sites page when you open new tabs. If you don’t see the Top Sites page in new tabs, change settings in General
>     preferences.